# Verification of a linear search with Frama-C

Tags: verification, frama-c

I'm yet again perplexed by a simple verification exercise, this time in Frama-C (Sodium) using the WP plugin, since I couldn't get Jessie to work on the uni workstations (in process of being installed by admin staff/team.) I have been reading 'ACSL by example' and the manual. Though I would think this example to be simple enough to get right very quickly. After using Dafny and Whiley to verify the same algorithm perhaps my has become a bit tainted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// A linear search over a sorted array looking for a given element.

/*@ requires len > 0;
  @ requires \valid( ls+ ( 0..(len - 1) ) );
  @ requires \forall size_t k; 0 <= k < (len - 1) ==> ls[k] <= ls[k + 1];
  @ assigns \nothing;
  @ behavior found:
  @   assumes \exists size_t k; 0 <= k < len && ls[k] == item;
  @   ensures \result >= 0;
  @ behavior nfound:
  @   assumes \forall size_t k; 0 <= k < len ==> ls[k] != item;
  @   ensures \result == -1;
  @ complete behaviors found, nfound;
  @ disjoint behaviors found, nfound;
  */
int search( int ls[], const size_t len, int item )
{
  size_t i = 0;

  /*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= len;
    @ loop invariant \forall size_t k; 0 <= k < i ==> ls[k] != item;
    @ loop assigns i;
    @ loop variant len - i;
    */
  while ( i < len )
  {
    if ( ls[i] == item )
      return i;
    ++i;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int src[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  if ( search( src, 10, 5 ) >= 0 ) printf( "found item" );
  else printf( "no item found" );
}
```

and the output I get when trying to verify this is:

```
$ frama-c -pp-annot -wp -wp-rte -wp-timeout 100 search.c    
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing search.c (with preprocessing)
/tmp/ppannot97a491.c:1:0: warning: "__STDC_VERSION__" redefined
 #define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L
 ^
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/tmp/ppannot97a491.c:2:0: warning: "__STDC_UTF_16__" redefined
 #define __STDC_UTF_16__ 1
 ^
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/tmp/ppannot97a491.c:3:0: warning: "__STDC_UTF_32__" redefined
 #define __STDC_UTF_32__ 1
 ^
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
[wp] Running WP plugin...
[wp] Collecting axiomatic usage
[rte] annotating function main
[rte] annotating function search
[wp] 20 goals scheduled
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_main_call_search_pre : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_main_call_search_pre_2 : Valid
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_complete_found_nfound : Valid (10ms) (19)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_loop_inv_preserved : Valid (17ms) (21)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_disjoint_found_nfound : Valid (13ms) (19)
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_loop_inv_established : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_loop_inv_2_established : Valid
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_main_call_search_pre_3 : Valid (383ms) (93)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_loop_inv_2_preserved : Valid (17ms) (33)
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_loop_assign : Valid
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_assert_rte_mem_access : Valid (50ms) (89)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_assert_rte_unsigned_overflow : Valid (13ms) (30)
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_assign_part1 : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_assign_part2 : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_assign_part3 : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_assign_part4 : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_loop_term_decrease : Valid (3ms)
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_search_loop_term_positive : Valid
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_nfound_post : Valid (17ms) (33)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_search_found_post : Unknown (54.3s)
[wp] Proved goals:   19 / 20
     Qed:            11  (3ms-3ms)
     Alt-Ergo:        8  (10ms-383ms) (93) (unknown: 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This puzzled me for a while, but after an attempt at a Coq proof, I figured out that the reason why you can't prove the `found` behavior is simply that ... it is **not** correct. Namely, for `len > INT_MAX` and an `item` which is not found in the `INT_MAX` first cells of the array but appears somewhere later, the result, as seen as an `int` will be negative.

Well, technically, this is implementation defined, as stated in C99, 6.3.1.3§3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in 
>   it; either the result is implementation-defined or an 
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

If you add the option `-warn-signed-downcast` to your command line, you will see a new RTE-generated assertion which is not proved:

```
     /*@ assert rte: signed_downcast: i ≤ 2147483647; */
```

Then the post-condition of the `found` behavior gets proved, under the hypothesis that said assertion holds.

Comment: Yes this is true but it was something the the other tools don't really deal with because of a very uniform use of 'int' throughout. basically C is the craziest can of worms ever in the history of programming (exaggerating.) I should have just stuck to Whiley and Dafny. Cheers for the enlightenment. Maybe I will come to like Frama-C one day.

Comment: actually Whiley and Dafny side step this issue but using unbounded integers throughout.